# Assignment of a pointer within a struct NOT WORKING, why is the value not changing?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, variable-assignment

For a school project I am supposed to implement a simplified version of the UNIX filesystem using only linked list structures. I am currently having a problem with my mkfs() function, which is supposed to simply initialize a filesystem.

My header file that creates the structures I am using is here:

```
typedef struct Lines {
  char line[82];
  struct Lines *next;
} Lines;

typedef struct Node {
  char *name;
  int id;
  struct Node *parent;
  struct Node *next;
  union {
    char line[82];
    struct Node *children;
  } contents;
} Node;

typedef struct Filesystem {
  char  *name;
  struct Node *root;
  struct Node *current;
} Filesystem;
```

Here is the method in my separate file which #includes this header file:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem *files) {
  Node *root = NULL; /* Creates a pointer to the directory we will use as
                      * the root directory for this filesystem*/

  files = (Filesystem *)malloc(sizeof(*files)); /* Allocates space for the the 
                             * filesystem structure */

  if(files == NULL){ /* If there is no memory available, prints error message
                      * and does nothing else */

    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");

   } else {

    root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(*root)); /* Allocates space for the root 
                   * directory of the filesystem. */


    if(root == NULL) { /* If there is no memory available, prints error
        * message and frees memory obtained thus far, but then 
        * does nothing else */

      printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
      free(files);

    } else {

  /* Allocates space for the root directory's name string */
      root->name= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen("/")+1));

      if(root->name == NULL) { /* If there is no memory available, prints error
            * message and frees memory obtained thus far, 
            * but then does nothing else */

    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");

    free(files);
    free(root);

      } else {

    root->name = "/"; /* Defines the root directory as being named by the
           * forward slash */ /* DO STR CPY HERE ITS CHANGING THE ADDRESS */
    root->contents.children = NULL;
    root->next = NULL;
    root->parent = NULL; /* UHH CHECK ON THIS NOOO CLUE IF ITS RIGHT FUUU*/

    files->root = root; /* The filesystems pointer to a directory is set 
             * to point to the root directory we just allocated
             * space for and set up */

    files->current = root; /* Sets the filesystems current directory to
            * point to the root directory as well, because 
            * it is the only directory in existence for this
            * filesystem at this point. */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I run gdb and step through each line, the last two assignment lines ARE NOT CHANGING the contents of file->root and file->current. 
For example, here I print the contents of files->root, run the line files->root = root, and then print again, and you can see the address has not changed. However if I just print root, the thing I am trying to assign it to, it clearly has a different value that files->root SHOULD have been set to:

```
(gdb) print files->root
$12 = (struct Node *) 0x400660
(gdb) step
(gdb) print files->root
$13 = (struct Node *) 0x400660
(gdb) print root
$14 = (Node *) 0x602030
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why an assignment might not work in this case? This is currently ruining my whole project, so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `mkfs` function is accepting a pointer to an already-existing `Filesystem` and then you are trying to allocate memory for a new `Filesystem` at a new memory location. There are two common conventions for a function like this: either it accepts no parameters and *returns* a pointer to a struct, or it accepts a pointer to an already-allocated struct and *populates* that struct. The reason it appears like the data isn't changing is that you're actually creating and populating a *second* struct, and leaving the caller's struct unchanged.

Here's an example of the first case, simplifying the function to just the memory allocation part:

```
Filesystem * mkfs() {
    Filesystem *files = (Filesystem *)malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));

    // (error handing omitted for brevity)

    // populate the files struct as appropriate...
    Node *root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    files->root = root;
    // etc, etc as you currently have

    return files;
}

// In this case you should also provide a way for the caller to free a filesystem,
// which will free everything you allocated during mkfs:
void freefs(Filessystem *files) {

    // first free any buffers you allocated inside the struct. For example:
    free(files->root);

    // then free the main filesystem struct
    free(files);
}
```

The caller then deals with this object using these two functions. For example:

```
int main() {
    Filesystem *files = mkfs();
    // now "files" is ready to use
    freefs(files); // free the objects when we're done with them.
}
```

Here's an example of the second case, which assumes that the caller already allocated an appropriate buffer, and it just needs to be populated:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem *files) {

    // populate the files struct as appropriate...
    Node *root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    files->root = root;
    // etc, etc as you currently have

}

void freefs(Filesystem *files) {
    // still need to clean up all of the ancillary objects
    free(files->root);
    // etc, etc
}
```

In this case the calling function has some more work to do. For example:

```
int main() {
    Filesystem *files = (Filesystem *)malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));
    mkfs(files);
    // now "files" is ready to use
    freefs(files); // free the objects when we're done with them.
}
```

Both patterns are valid; the former is useful if you expect that the caller will need to be able to control how memory is allocated. For example, the caller might decide to allocate the filesystem on the stack rather than the heap:

```
int main() {
    Filesystem files;
    mkfs(&files);
    // now "files" is ready to use
    freefs(&files); // free the ancillary objects when we're done with them.
    // "files" is still allocated here, but it's no longer valid
}
```

The latter takes care of the allocation on behalf of the caller. Since your function allocates further structures on the heap it's necessary to include a cleanup function in both cases.

Comment: Well the function definition was given to me by the teacher so I have to follow it. The testing code is doing this in its main method:
Filesystem filesystem;
mkfs(&filesystem);

Comment: I can't get around that, that's the way the tests are defined.

Comment: If the teacher is telling you to pass in the pointer then that forces you to take the second path. (I published the answer before I'd really finished it; I'm sorry for the confusion.) One of my examples towards the end shows the same setup you have in your assignment, with the caller allocating the filesystem on the stack and passing it in to the `mkfs` function.

Comment: Okay well I am not allowed to change the main method (which is exactly that very last piece of code you wrote), and I am not allowed to change the function declaration. So are you saying if the main makes this kind of call, I do not need to do any allocation once I get into mkfs()?

Comment: The `freefs` thing is good style (to avoid memory leaks) but not necessary for an academic assignment, so don't worry about it. But yes, if `main` passes in a pointer to a buffer then you don't need to allocate another one, you can just assign into that buffer directly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, this is only one of the many methods we are implementing, so there are other functions I wrote that will free the necessary memory, but I didn't include those because they weren't relevant to the problem

Comment: But anyway, thank you so much for your help, this solved the problem. I've been stuck on this for the past four hours and haven't been able to make any headway, so this was really a life saver. I really appreciate how quickly you responded, and the amount of detail you gave.

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck with the rest of the assignment, and please consider marking this as your accepted answer. :)